# How to use hashed passwords with BASIC authentication in tomcat6?

Tags: tomcat, hash, basic-authentication, sha

I want to use hashed passwords in tomcat-users.xml with BASIC authentication. I added digest="SHA" to realm definition. UserDatabase part is defined as this in $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml:

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
<Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
          type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
          description="User database that can be updated and saved"
          factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
          pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
</GlobalNamingResources>
...
<Engine>
...
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
             digest="SHA"
             resourceName="UserDatabase" />  
...
</Engine>
```

But after restart tomcat still treats all defined in $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.xml passwords as plain-text ones.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
<user username="guest" password="e5e9fa1ba31ecd1ae84f75caaa474f3a663f05f4" roles="role1" />
</tomcat-users>
```

I.e. I can login with username/password guest/e5e9fa1ba31ecd1ae84f75caaa474f3a663f05f4, but not with guest/secret as it should be.

Please point me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: OK, looks like something rewrites realm definition in web application, since /manager/ worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution should work up to Tomcat 7, but starting from Tomcat 8 you have to specify the `CredentialHandler` section inside `Realm` as shown below:

**Tomcat 6...7:**

```xml
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
             digest="sha"
             resourceName="UserDatabase" />
```

**Tomcat 8:**

```xml
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
             resourceName="UserDatabase">
           <CredentialHandler
              className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler"     
              algorithm="sha" />
      </Realm>
```

---

**NB:** For more secure hashing, like PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40936407/485343).