# Tomcat - Understanding CredentialHandler

Tags: java, tomcat, authentication

I need to use Container Managed Security and Authentication in my latest
project. And I have a couple of queries regarding how to configure a
Credential Handler.

1. Firstly how will a [CredentialHandler](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/credentialhandler.html) declaration look like ? **Can
   someone provide a sample declaration of the NestedCredentialHandler with
   the algorithm attribute declared. I need to know since the Digest attribute
   in Realms has become deprecated.** I didn't find any examples on the web and
   I am utterly confused.
2. Whats the difference between `MessageDigestCredentialHandler` and
   `SecretKeyCredentialHandler` which one is more secure ?
3. `SecretKeyCredentialHandler` specifies **only one algorithm** in the
   [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/credentialhandler.html) which is `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1`. What other algorithms are
   available ?

Answer (score 14):

To answer the first point, here's a comparison of the `<Realm>` from my  context.xml before and after the switch to Tomcat 8:

**Before:**

```xml
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm"
       dataSourceName="jdbc/myDataSource"  
       roleNameCol="role" userCredCol="password" userNameCol="loginid" 
       digest="md5" 
       userRoleTable="userroles" userTable="users" 
       localDataSource="true" />
```

**After:**

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm" 
       dataSourceName="jdbc/myDataSource" 
       roleNameCol="role" userCredCol="password" userNameCol="loginid"      
       userRoleTable="userroles" userTable="users" localDataSource="true">
       <CredentialHandler
          className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler"     
 algorithm="md5" />
</Realm>
```

Answer (score 7):

NestedCredentialHandler is for cases when you have multiple digest methods, for example you have used MessageDigest in the past but now you want to switch a more secure PBKDF2-SHA512 configuration, and don't want to make already configured passwords invalid.

For example:

```
<CredentialHandler className="org.apache.catalina.realm.NestedCredentialHandler">
   <CredentialHandler className="org.apache.catalina.realm.SecretKeyCredentialHandler"
                      algorithm="PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512"
                      iterations="100000"
                      keyLength="256"
                      saltLength="16"
   />
   <CredentialHandler className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler"
                      algorithm="SHA-256"
                      iterations="1000"
                      keyLength="256"
                      saltLength="8"
   />
</CredentialHandler>

<!-- NOTE: keyLength is in bits, saltLength is in bytes. 16 bytes = 128 bits -->
```

This would go inside your Realm element.

SecretKeyCredentialHandler was introduced in Tomcat 8.0.15 and uses SecretKeyFactory from the javax.crypto API rather than the old method (MessageDigest) to mutate the password. SecretKeyFactory allows for better algorithms such as PBKDF2 with HMAC-SHA-512 rather than plain hash algorithms such as SHA-512. The old method is since available via MessageDigestCredentialHandler, which is equivalent of setting the digest attribute on the Realm element directly.

**Please note**, setting the digest attribute directly or using MessageDigestCredentialHandler without the optional iteration attribute (8.0.15+ only) will only do *one* iteration. **This is NOT secure**.

As for what algorithms are available for SecretKeyFactory, the [Java Cryptography Architecture Standard Algorithm Name Documentation for JDK 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#SecretKeyFactory) is the best reference I could find, but it doesn't list all combinations explicitly. These were the ones I found working on my platform (Linux 3.13.0, Oracle JDK 1.8.0_111), but yours may support other combinations.

- PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1
- PBKDF2WithHmacSHA224
- PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256
- PBKDF2WithHmacSHA384
- PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512
- PBEWithMD5AndDES
- PBEWithSHA1AndDESede
- DES
- DESede

Comment: If anybody needs, you can generate a encrypted password and then add it into your database this way: `.\digest.bat -a "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512" -i 100000 -s 16 -k 256 -h "org.apache.catalina.realm.SecretKeyCredentialHandler" <password>`, replacing <password> by the desired password (plain text).

Comment: And if you would like to debug this configuration see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311496/how-to-debug-realm-feature-in-tomcat

Answer (score 3):

I have a requirement to deploy the same myapp.war binary file to Tomcat7 and Tomcat8 environments. Using this configuration both environments work fine.

**myapp/META-INF/context.xml**

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm"
    dataSourceName="jdbc/myapp" localDataSource="true" digest="SHA-256"
    userTable="user_role_v"     userNameCol="username" userCredCol="password"   
    userRoleTable="user_role_v" roleNameCol="role">
    <CredentialHandler className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler" 
       algorithm="SHA-256" iterations="1" saltLength="0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" />
  </Realm>
```

You see a warning in catalina log file at startup for unknown parameter but it does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm field of MessageDigestCredentialHandler is a string that can take any of the values described here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#MessageDigest

The difference between MessageDigestCredentialHandler and SecretKeyHandler is the algorithms to use, I think, SecretKeyHandler is more secure because of the javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.

I can't provide any sample of configuration, but when I worked with TomcatRealms implementing custom AuthorizationProviders I always configured it in META-INF/context.xml

Finally, I would like to advise you, for years I have bee working with custom AuthorizationProviders, but now I migrated all of them to Spring Security.

Comment: Know any place where I can get the example of configuring the Credential Handler ?

Comment: Sorry I can't, but i think it is possible to add

Comment: Sorry I can't, but i think it is possible to add CredentialHandler node inside Realm configuration in the META-INF/context.xml file. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30330576/get-instance-of-datasourcerealm-from-a-servlet)