# Tomcat 8 - Database realm configuration

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, md5

I have configured tomcat 7 server to use MD5 digest in database realm configuration.
It worked fine.
Now I need to upgrade my servers to tomcat 8.
But it generates a different hash for my my passwords in database.
How can I configure it to generate same old values?
I have already copied jdbc driver jars to lib folder in tomcat 8 and made all sh files in bin executable.

In simple, how can I make below two outputs equal.
Tomcat 7:

```
~/apache-tomcat-7.0.69/bin$ ./digest.sh -a MD5 test
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
test:098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6
~/apache-tomcat-7.0.69/bin$
```

Tomcat 8:

```
~/apache-tomcat-8.5.6/bin$ ./digest.sh -a MD5 test
test:27d6262696d98e0a8a973d43eef07c66c68b089a4ada21dd3ba0defc04ca302e$1$13a7c1932523dcea3bb39ef05b75b4c6
~/apache-tomcat-8.5.6/bin$
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38937341/4595123) solved my question.

To answer the first point, here's a comparison of the `<Realm>` from my context.xml before and after the switch to Tomcat 8:

**Before:**

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm"
    dataSourceName="jdbc/myDataSource"  
    roleNameCol="role" userCredCol="password" userNameCol="loginid" 
    digest="md5" 
    userRoleTable="userroles" userTable="users" 
    localDataSource="true" />
```

**After:**

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm"
    dataSourceName="jdbc/myDataSource" 
    roleNameCol="role" userCredCol="password" userNameCol="loginid"      
    userRoleTable="userroles" userTable="users" localDataSource="true">
    <CredentialHandler
    className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler"     
    algorithm="md5" />
</Realm>
```

Comment: This worked for me. I used it with :

<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
   driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"