# tomcat form-based authentication DataSourceRealm configuration errors

Tags: java, xml, apache, servlets

I'm new to tomcat development. I've tried configuration for form-based authentication on tomcat server. But errors appear in log file logs/catalina.out. I'm not sure whether there is any error in conf/server.xml or application/WEB-INF/web.xml.
tomcat/logs/catalina.out outputs:

> WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule.begin
>   [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Realm} Setting property
>   'digest' to 'MD5' did not find a matching property.
>   WARNING [main]
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement   No rules found
>   matching     'Server/Service/Engine/Resource'.

In tomcat/conf/server.xml

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm"
    localDataSource="true"
    digest="MD5"
    dataSourceName="jdbc/test"
    userTable="users"
    userNameCol="user_name"
    userCredCol="user_pass"
    userRoleTable="user_roles"
    roleNameCol="role_name"/>

<Resource name="jdbc/test"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"
    username="he"
    password="***"
    maxActive="8"
    maxIdle="4"
    maxWait="10000"
    auth="Container"/>
```

In application/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>UpdateRe</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern> 
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>Admin</role-name>
        <role-name>Member</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-role>
    <role-name>Admin</role-name>
    <role-name>Member</role-name>
    <role-name>Guest</role-name>
</security-role>    

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.html</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/loginError.html</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>  
</login-config>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely you have Tomcat8.5 where digest attribute is removed. You need to use CredentialHandler sub element. [This answer has an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41509359/185565) how to support both Tomcat7 and Tomcat8 server in a same myapp.war file.

Most of the documentation online about the `org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm` point to previous configuration.