# Tomcat SecretKeyCredentialHandler Attributes?

Tags: java, authentication, tomcat, tomcat9

### Question:

Does Tomcat 9 Realm `<CredentialHandler>` need the proper algorithm parameters to hash a password and authenticate a user from a password?

My webapp seems to be able to authenticate a user no matter what parameters I pass the PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512 algorithm, even when the attributes on the `<CredentialHandler>` element are different, or without any attributes.

Is this the expected behavior of Tomcat's Realm? If so, how can this be? Is the Realm able to deduce the parameters from the composition of the hash?

### Background:

Tomcat 9 offers container-managed security with a Realm based on Java's [SecretKeyFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#SecretKeyFactory) algorithms.

I am using PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512, which has options:

- Iterations
- Key Length
- Salt Length

My CredentialHandler as defined in my webapp's `context.xml` is

```
<CredentialHandler
    className="org.apache.catalina.realm.SecretKeyCredentialHandler"
    algorithm="PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512"
    iterations="100000"
    keyLength="256"
    saltLength="16">
</CredentialHandler>
```

A Tomcat installation offers CLI access to the hashing algorithm at `CATALINA_HOME/bin/digest.[bat|sh]`. (See the [Tomcat 9 Realm Configuration HOW-To](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/realm-howto.html#Digested_Passwords) for more details.)

No matter the options I pass to the CLI hashing algorithm, Tomcat is able to authenticate the user correctly from the DataSource Realm (MySQL database). The password can be successfully authenticated against both of the following:

Example #1 matches `<CredentialHandler>`:

```
$ $CATALINA_HOME/bin/digest.sh -a PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512 -i 100000 -s 
16 -k 256 -h org.apache.catalina.realm.SecretKeyCredentialHandler passw0rd 
passw0rd:d0c315b015272b531b0a82cec220d4a1$100000$7ac32ed573fe81e75f611a46622573515
ad11d731dcae4839973ae2702774c51
```

Example #2 different parameters:

```
$ $CATALINA_HOME/bin/digest.sh -a PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512 -i 100 -s 1 -k 128 
-h org.apache.catalina.realm.SecretKeyCredentialHandler passw0rd
passw0rd:47$100$0e4790b617fa24ee324d55bed38ad4b0
```

### Also See

- [Tomcat - Understanding CredentialHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32178822/tomcat-understanding-credentialhandler)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is the expected behavior of Tomcat Realm with a *SecretKeyCredentialHandler* as *CredentialHandler* defined. Tomcat does not need the iterations, salt or key parameters in context.xml, to authenticate a user from a password.

### How is this possible?

If you look into the tomcat [documentation of the SecretKeyCredentialHandler](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/credentialhandler.html#SecretKeyCredentialHandler), you will notice that the stored passwords is defined as:

> **salt $ iterationCount $ encodedCredential** - a hex encoded salt, iteration code and a hex encoded credential, each separated by $.

The *salt* and *iterationCount* used for encryption are part of the stored password. Tomcat don't uses the values of the *CredentialHandler*-Tag from *context.xml* for decryption. It uses the values from the password itself. If you look inside your two generated passwords, you will find salt and iterationCount in it, formated in the defined pattern.

### Why do i have to set the values in context.xml anyway?

You don't have to. For decryption, only the algorithm-attribute value from *context.xml* it used. So, for what are the other attributes? Reading carefully the [Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/credentialhandler.html) gives the answer:

> The CredentialHandler can also be used to generate a new stored version of a given credential that would be required, for example, when adding a new user to a Realm or when changing a user's password.

and

> **iterations** - The number of iterations to use when *creating a new*
> stored credential from a clear text credential.
>
> **saltLength** - The length of the randomly generated salt to use when
> *creating a new* stored credential from a clear text credential.
>
> **keyLength** - The length of *key to generate for the stored
> credential*. If not specified, a default of 160 is used.

These *CredentialHandler*-Tag attributs from *context.xml* are used when creating a new password via CredentialHandler (see method *mutate* in [API](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/CredentialHandler.html#mutate(java.lang.String))). Its used for encryption to create a new password, not for decryption of existing passwords.